# neo4j EmbeddedNeo4j.java in maven try-with-resources error

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, try-with-resources

I'm attempting to run the first example in the Neo4j Manual chapter 32 on using Neo4j embedded in Java applications, the file is `EmbeddedNeo4j.java`, I'm using maven, with the proper Neo4j dependency. I'm getting a compilation error that seems to indicate I'm using Java 1.5, but everything I see tells me I'm using Java 1.7.

Here's the error:

```
EmbeddedNeo4j.java:[71,12] error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
```

Here's why I think Maven should be using Java 1.7:

> [root@cerif t02]# mvn -version
>   Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 13:51:28+0000)
>   Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
>   Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "3.9.3-x86-linode52", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
>   [root@cerif t02]#

Any advice on tracking down why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

Have you told Maven to use Java 1.7 compatibility mode?

If not, try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: mvn install succeeded after adding this build clause.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Based on warnings, I added a version line after the artifactId:             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>

Comment: Ahh, yes, I forgot about that.  I'll update my answer so that it's acceptable to you.